# How to include Thread Stack Trace into log using SLF4jJ over LOG4J

Tags: java

Is there any way to include thread stack trace into logs by using SLF4J?

Can it be automated or do we have to add it in log message?

is there any properties that can be include Stack trace?

can any one please share the code and properties file please?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a "new Throwable()" at the end of the parameters typically does that.
E.g.

```
log.warn("Why am I here?", new Throwable());
```

or, as pointed out below, the exception caught when you have that.

Comment: If you are logging an error in a `catch` block, use the exception/throwable that you just caught.

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing -- `log.error("your message", exceptionObject);` in your catch block.
It's important to at least post what you have done / tried / facing issue somewhere. If you need property file configurations for logging then tons of good tutorials are available online. [link-to-tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/log4j-tutorial/).

HTH.